# How to Install Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: system-installation

I have bit of a problem.
I have no idea how to install the Ubuntu 13.04.
The only thing I have is USB. My machine is Intel i3 with Windows 8 already installed but I am kind of tired of Windows so I decided to make my 8 gb ram 1 tb HD. a dual boot.
Any Help Is appreciated ! :)

Comment: There is a wealth of information in the above link that will be helpful to you. Especially, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key

Comment: @searchfgold6789 [That](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)'s an excellent question, but probably not about what Alan is looking for (though making people aware of the techniques described there is a good thing). That is for creating a portable, fully functional Ubuntu installation on a USB flash drive. Alan probably wants to install Ubuntu *on the hard disk* through the use of a USB flash drive *as an installation medium*.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent guide at the Community Wiki [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall) that will guide you step by step through the installation procedure. First, though, you will have to [download](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GettingUbuntu) and then [burn](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#From_Windows) the Ubuntu .iso file to your USB disk. There are also general [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Booting_the_Computer_from_USB) on how to set up your BIOS to boot from your USB disk if, after rebooting with the USB key plugged in, nothing happens.